# PHP large file uploading making other post variables invalid

Tags: php, file, upload

I'm trying to upload large files from html form with action having a simple php file. Now what's happening is when I try to upload small files less than 4 or 5 mb, the form works fine and gets submitted. But if I try large files like more than 40-50 mb, it gives me error, that other `$_POST['variables']` are invalid/undefined. I have even used following in my script top:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000)

ini_set('post_max_size', '256M')

ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '256M');

ini_set("memory_limit", "256M");
```

Comment: `ini_set()` is not allowed on all webhosters, what says `ini_get`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request to your webhoster for increase upload_max_filesize,post_max_size,memory_limit,max_execution_time in php.ini.

So Your problem is resolved.
I am also got that problem in Hostgator server.I resolve by request given parameters above increase.